# Form data empty when emitting it in a socket

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

```
# Frontend

const convertFormData = (message: MessageType) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    if (message.attachments!.length !== 0) {
      message.attachments!.forEach((attachment: AttachedType) => {
        formData.append("files", attachment.file, attachment.name);
      });
    }
    if (message.message) {
      formData.append("chat", message.message);
    }
    formData.append("userUno", message.userUno);
    formData.append("userDos", message.userDos);
    return formData;
  };

  const sendMessage = (message: MessageType) => {
    const formData = convertFormData(message);
    events.emit<FormData>(formData, EventEnum.SEND);
   }

# Backend

const sendMessage = async (formData: FormData, room: number) => {
    console.log(formData);
    io.to(room.toString()).emit(MessageEnum.RECEIVE, formData);
  };
```

The problem is that the form data is empty when i send it to the socket.

I try converting the data to json and tried to send it to the socket server but that also did not work.

Comment: What's the `events` variable? Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example